# WCF service with a version for DEV, QA and PROD

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services

First off, I did look on google and stackoverflow, but nothing seem to really meet my desires.

That said.  I am using an MVC application (It could just as well be a Web Forms app) that I inherited from a previous developer(s).  The current Service References point at production servers and I would like to simply point also at local dev servers.  Ideally I would like to not edit the web.config file for changing from dev to prod (especially if it is for several places etc..)

Thus, perhaps there is a "best practice" for adding extra web references and being able to quickly "swap and test" the DEV references to PROD references with very little configuration changes.

Perhaps a design pattern, or an appconfig setting to facilitate this process?  It certainly would be ideal to keep it loosely coupled with constructor injection of the service references.  Any thoughts on how to best implement this?

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio 2010, then the best practice is to use Web.config transforms. Otherwise, the best practice is to edit web.config. That's what it's for.

Comment: @JohnSaunders   Thanks for the response.  So if I am seeing  the following                                                          `using (ContractService.ContractServiceContractClient client = new ContractService.ContractServiceContractClient()) { ContractService.AddContractCommentRequest request = new ContractService.AddContractCommentRequest();`  then I certainly want to be adding a new Contract Service pointing at the same name? but in vs 2010 just editing the tranforms section?

Comment: I use dns entry in my hosts file for this purpose.

For example In production environment, services are hosted in services.myapplication.com.
I have a copy of the services in my local machine, to which my hosts file will forward the requests.

Is this bad practice? I can change it to any environment (prod/test/dev or local) I want ... without changing even the config file.

Comment: @Romi  Hmm, that is interesting.  Certainly one way of doing it.  I'm really hoping that somebody has a couple of good opinions, maybe a blog someone has seen or wrote...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option would be to add multiple endpoint configurations for the same service that point to different addresses. Then when you create a new instance of your service client you pass the name of then endpoint configuration.

```
ContractServiceContractClient client = 
new ContractServiceContractClient("DEV_Endpoint");
```

or

```
ContractServiceContractClient client = 
new ContractServiceContractClient("PROD_Endpoint");
```

And in your ServiceReference config

```
<endpoint address="http://localhost:7821/ContractService.svc"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" 
          bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ContractService"
          contract="ContractServiceReference.IContractService" 
          name="DEV_Endpoint" />
```

or

```
<endpoint address="http://service.apps.com/ContractService.svc"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" 
          bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ContractService"
          contract="ContractServiceReference.IContractService" 
          name="PROD_Endpoint" />
```

Then if you just create a global static string or put something in your app.config that contains the name of the endpoint configuration you want to use, then you just have to change it in that one spot and it will update across the application.

The only catch here is that you can't create an instance of your service client without passing which endpoint configuration you want to use if you have more than one endpoint configuration for the same contract.

Comment: Ok, so far I am liking this.  However, say I'm wanting to use constructor injection and need to decide which to use.  I suppose that I need to keep this a bit abstract.  Overall that looks good.  I'm just trying to get away from direct newing up of dependencies.  How would you handle the logic in decided between the two with keeping the code loosely coupled with DI etc.. ?

Comment: You can always just use a property.

    private String EndPoint {
        get {
            if (...some condition)
               return this.ProdEndpoint;
            else
               return this.DevEndpoint;
        }
    }

Then for the condition you could run a check for a constant that contains a value that indicates which endpoint to use. Then you can have the different endpoints stored as constants as well.

Comment: This only works if you assume that the services in Dev and Prod are always the same and only are pointing to different resources. You won't be able to use this approach in case anything in the functionality of the web service changes in one environment.

Answer (score 0):

what I usually do is to have all settings in the database, and we have different database connection strings (machines are different) for each environment.

in the app/web.config we simply change 1 key specifying to which environment we are pointing then everything else comes from the settings table in the database which contains different values per environment. For service references the checked-in code always and only points to localhost and at runtime the url is assigned from the settings retrieved from the db.

Comment: Yes, I see what you are saying.  In this case I don't have a database table or environment setup that I would want to store it in a database though. That certainly looks to be an option.  Thanks.

Comment: "we simply change 1 key" : Is this autodetected value assignement or do you have to do it manually evertime you publish? If it is, on what do you base your investigation?